# Render preview in viewport shows correctly but not in final rendered image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, uv, eevee-render-engine, geometry-nodes

So I generated this UV map with the use of Attributes in Geometry nodes, and I got it to work correctly in both Rendered preview and Material preview. But when I try to render final image (both Cycles and Evee) the texture is not displaying correctly.
Am I missing something basic here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the file/node setup?

Comment: Ok, I just did, but it will miss the texture. You can probably use any other texture. The point is that the UVMap is somehow not getting through to the renderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object "cube.end" has a modifier bevel, that's enabled on render:

[image]

which makes different count of vertices and makes impossible to transfer attribute by face index correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Crantiz! this actually solved the problem! I would never catch this on my own. I assumed the modifier was applied after the uvmap. Thank you again